In a "select * where col=x" where x is non-orderable, non-indexed column, does a database give any performance gain over a flat file?
If I am querying a database to select all records that have a VARCHAR() field equal to a query parameter. Is there any speed advantage to doing a linear line-by-line search of a flat-file "database?" If so, how is this speedup accomplished?

Since you're using varchar data, the location of each of your fields within the file is not well defined.  There is an overhead in "parsing" each line of the file to locate the field on which you wish to filter.
In a database table, the location of each field is well-defined, making it quicker to locate each value.
Low-level file I/O may also be quicker, since the table will be read from disk in [larger] [database] blocks.
Reading a file line-by-line will generally be slower.
Subsequent queries on the same table may be even quicker, because the file I/O may be eliminated entirely, with the database blocks being cached in an in-memory Buffer within the database.  Filtering is now done all in memory.
Reading from a file will always .. well .. read from the file, which will be slower than in-memory activity.
Databases allow many processes to read from (and, even, write to) the same table at [much] the same time.  Handling that sort of contention at the file level is horribly complicated.
